# Hi i am trying to log defect in hp alm. I wrote a java programm. Its giving me error 500. Because i am trying to put the same id

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, marshalling

i fetched the defect url:

```
   String defectUrl = conn.buildEntityCollectionUrl("defect");
    defectUrl += "/98";

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    requestHeaders.put("Accept", "application/xml");

    Response res = conn.httpGet(defectUrl, null, requestHeaders);
```

then converted into Entity:

```
    String postedEntityReturnedXml = res.toString();
    Entity entity = EntityMarshallingUtils.marshal(Entity.class,postedEntityReturnedXml);
```

than change the field value:

```
    List<Field> fields = entity.getFields().getField();

    for (Field f : fields) {
        if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        {
            int i=f.hashCode();
            System.out.println(i);
            f.getValue().clear();
            f.setName("");
        }
    }
```

now trying to convert it to xml formate again:

```
    String xml = EntityMarshallingUtils.unmarshal(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.class,**fields**);
    System.out.println(xml);
```

throwing error as object fields should not be there and not able to get what should i put in place of fields?

my EntityMarshallingUtils class is like:

```
package org.hp.qc.web.restapi.docexamples.docexamples.infrastructure;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
//import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
public class EntityMarshallingUtils {
 private EntityMarshallingUtils() {}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T marshal(Class<T> c, String xml) throws JAXBException     {
        T res;

        if (c == xml.getClass()) {
            res = (T) xml;
        }

        else {
            JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
            Unmarshaller marshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
            res = (T) marshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        }

        return res;
    }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> String unmarshal(Class<T> c, Object o) throws  Exception {

        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter entityXml = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(o, entityXml);

        String entityString = entityXml.toString();

        return entityString;
    }

 }
```

AnyOne who can help me on this?